# SNMP MIB development tool

Tags: snmp, mib

Does anybody know a good tool to assist in the development of an SNMP MIB with correct formatting and syntax?

If possible, it should be free and run under Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You could always use the [snmp-mode](http://simon.nitro.dk/dotfiles/emacs/snmp-mode.el) in emacs for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

For a very quick & dirty systax-hightlighter, try the default color [syntax highlighting in vim](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-or-off-color-syntax-highlighting-in-vi-or-vim/). Below is a screenshot from a MIB-II file in vim.

[image]

Comment: For this to work it seems to be necessary to choose the right filename extension, e.g. '.mib'

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Writing_your_own_MIBs) net-snmp howto, there is a tool called [smilint](http://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/smilint.html) from the [smilib](http://www.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/) package that they recommend. Sounds more directed than using snmptranslate.

See also [this](http://www.ops.ietf.org/mib-review-tools.html) ietf page for descriptions on usage.

Comment: Actually I am aware of these tools and am quite comfortable with writing SNMP MIBS.  I wasn't really looking for a syntax checker, rather a tool which will speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [MIB Explorer Lite](http://www.mibexplorer.com/download/download.html) which has a syntax checker whenever you load a MIB.  There's a free trial which I think lasts about 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

I used http://www.mibdesigner.com/ couple of times and I find it to be a valuable tool significantly reducing the MIB design time.

It allows me to easily reorder parts of MIB and rename OIDs. More important it checks not only for invalid syntax but also for commonly used design and recommendation violations. The output is nicely formatted.